# Updating entry WITHOUT updating timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I have a timestamp in a mysql table with attribute "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP". Is there a way to manually disable updating the timestamp on a special occasion? (eg: updating the entry to revise a blog post, but not to re-date it)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> Is there a way to manually disable updating the timestamp on a special occasion? (eg: updating the entry to revise a blog post, but not to re-date it)

Sounds like you need to configure the default constraint so that it populates the column on insertion only:

```
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Changing it to only be this means that any revisions will not trigger the timestamp value to be updated.  IE: If you created the blogpost yesterday, and corrected a typo today - the date in the column would still be for yesterday.

Comment: Can you show an SQL statement for updating the field for others, I figured it out for myself?

Comment: What if i want to update the `last_updated` field (keep `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` behaviour) as usual **except if update was made only on one particular column**? Actually I'm modelling a *meta-data db* to persist information of certain `cron`s (their *source, sink, last_completion_time*). So I the `last_updated` field must be updated only when the cron was *actually modified* (and not when cron's `last_completion_time` field was updated)

Answer (score 167):

You can manually set the value of the column to its current value in the update command:

```
UPDATE table SET x=y, timestampColumn=timestampColumn WHERE a=b;
```

If you don't set the value in the query, it will be updated to the current timestamp as per the table definition.

Comment: "slower" - how much? Longer than it takes the OP to remove the magic `ON UPDATE`, add `NOW()` to all his other queries and retest his app?

Comment: How much slower depends on the number of rows you're updating. If you're working with system logs with literally millions of rows then it's not just slow -- it's slow every time you run that query.
I'm not suggesting removing `DEFAULT` value; just the `ON UPDATE`

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I needed. I have table "blogposts" and when I update view count it updates the "datetime_edited" (on update timestamp)  column. On every other occasion I need "datetime_edited" field updated - title or description changes, new image upload etc.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once! I didn't even know you could refer to a column in the record in an update statement! A whole new world!

Comment: Thank you, this is excellent solution, exactly what I need. Recommend.

Comment: thnx for ur solution Boss

Comment: open another window for me.

Answer (score 27):

To make your table/timestamp auto-update:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
CHANGE myTimestampColumn
        myTimestampColumn TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
                       DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
                       ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

To make it ***not*** auto-update:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
CHANGE myTimestampColumn
        myTimestampColumn TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
                       DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

NOTE: The "default current_timestamp" part just sets it to the current stamp at default time, since the field is not-null.  You can remove both the not null and the default, if you like.

Answer (score 12):

Don't use timestamps, but track times manually.

If you really want to update a record and don't update its timestamp, use:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `timestamp` = `timestamp`, `col` = 'new data' …;
```

to overwrite the timestamp with its current value.

Comment: "don't use timestamps", why?

Comment: They can only represent times from 1.1.1970 to 31.12.2037; only the first timestamp column is automatically updated; when restoring from a backup timestamps are adjusted to the local timezone. And, depending on your application, you might not want to have that column updated when running an sql update statement in your backand (you only want the timestamp updated when using your frontend to edit data)

Comment: Timestamps are explicitly intended to track PRESENT times, so there's no problem with it having limited range of values. "Only first column" is not a problem either, and assuming you are using at least MySQL 4.1.3, local timezone is not an issue, if you've used mysqldump for backup.

Comment: Adding to what @AnrDaemon states, I'm sure we'll get support for date ranges beyond 2037 long before we approach that cut off, and transitioning historical data to the new timestamp format should be very easy (if not automatic).  Also, MySQL has supported multiple timestamp columns at least since v5.6.10 was released in early 2013.  And if you don't want a timestamp value to update when a record is updated, then don't specify ON UPDATE...

Answer (score 0):

If you do change timestemp on update then you have to take into your consideration that if the value was updated but not changed (updated the save value) then it will not update the "on update Current_timestemp" and on this situation you should set the timestemp manually

```
SET LastUpdatedDate=NOW() WHERE
```

The idea came from here: 
[Touch MYSQL record to update TIMESTAMP field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21596941/touch-mysql-record-to-update-timestamp-field)