# Timestamp without change on update

Tags: mysql

In mysql I have a `timestamp` with the field name `added_on`. I created that for a table of leads for a crm. But it's getting updated whenever I update a lead. I only want the timestamp to show only the added time. I dont want that to get updated everytime when I update or make changed in the lead.

Note: while creating the timestamp field i gave default value as timestamp and it shows `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`  in the extras field after creating the field.

any ideas to stop the timestamp getting updated whenever I update the row?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Updating entry WITHOUT updating timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844863/mysql-updating-entry-without-updating-timestamp)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue is the `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.  You *should* be able to undo this behavior with an alter statement like this (not sure what your table name is):

```
ALTER TABLE leads MODIFY added_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: my table name is lead. Nice guess though. Thanks alot adam :) it worked exactly the same way i wanted. Wish i could vote up. but i couldn't due to low rep points. :(

Answer (score 4):

If you want control over the timestamp, just change it to DATETIME and then update it yourself when you want to with `added_on=NOW()`

This is what I do to avoid complications, then you can be sure that you have complete control over it, which is also useful for archiving or moving data between tables, because you would not want the timestamp to update itself in this case.

Comment: Caution: DATETIME does not automatically perform timezone calculations when dates are stored and retrieved, TIMESTAMP does. This will impact any applications that need to be timezone aware, so this is not a universal solution.

Answer (score 3):

The first TIMESTAMP of a table, by default has ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. To prevent this (instead of altering the table afterwards) see the MySQL docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html):

> TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns have no automatic properties unless
>   they are specified explicitly, with this exception: By default, the
>   first TIMESTAMP column has both DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON
>   UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP if neither is specified explicitly. To
>   suppress automatic properties for the first TIMESTAMP column, use one
>   of these strategies:
>
> 1) Enable the explicit_defaults_for_timestamp system variable. If this
>   variable is enabled, the DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP clauses that specify automatic initialization and
>   updating are available, but are not assigned to any TIMESTAMP column
>   unless explicitly included in the column definition.
>
> 2) Alternatively, if explicit_defaults_for_timestamp is disabled (the
>   default), do either of the following:
>
> 2a) Define the column with a DEFAULT clause that specifies a constant
>   default value.
>
> 2b) Specify the NULL attribute. This also causes the column to permit NULL
>   values, which means that you cannot assign the current timestamp by
>   setting the column to NULL. Assigning NULL sets the column to NULL.

Answer (score 2):

You added a `ON UPDATE` condition to the column!!
To remove this, redefine the column as

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` MODIFY `added_on` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

This will effectively remove the `ON UPDATE` condition.

Comment: This is wrong.  See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html.  About halway down: "By default, the first TIMESTAMP column has both DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP if neither is specified explicitly."