# How to solve date automatic update in database?

Tags: php, mysql, view

I am using now() function for article published date and also article views counter.I am using following query

```
mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE posts SET article_views = article_views+1 where id = '$post_id'");
```

problem is that the date is also updated by this query. so how i can solve this problem.

Comment: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131725/timestamp-without-change-on-update

Comment: yes i am using your format in database but this is not solution

Comment: why what problem with that ? @sam

Comment: i don't know sir. i am showing 500 characters of article and read more link. when i click on read more link then views is increment by one and date also update with current date.

Comment: @sam see the link provided by Michael O. You will find your solution there

Comment: great @MichaelO. that is the solution for me