# SQL query that is bugged in a way I don't understand

Tags: mysql, sql

I know the title is weird, but I am on that same bug for HOURS.

I have this query

`UPDATE tournaments SET password_req_count = password_req_count + 1 WHERE id = 20;`

(You can replace 20 by anything, it really does not matter)

This query modifies a timestamp field called `start_timestamp` by ALWAYS setting it the computers current hour.

And this query is perfectly fine, there's no bug with this :

`UPDATE tournaments SET password_req_count = 0 WHERE id = 20;`

This was happening in the PHP code until I removed that one query, then it stopped. Then I decided to try it by directly executing the query myself, without PHP, and the bug is still here.

`password_req_count` is an int (I mean, I checked it, the problem isn't here)

This query does not appear in the query history of MySQL (the one you can get by pressing the "UP" key to remake a query quickly...), and this bug doesn't appear locally (it only appears on my server). Note that I exported my local database to the server's one, so everything is exactly the same there and here.

The MySQL server version was 5.5 on my server and 5.7 at home, I thought this was the problem so I updated it, but absolutely nothing changed. I also googled a lot about this, but I found no topic talking about this subject.

I do have query logs, so I am SURE that there is NOTHING that edits the start_timestamp (except this weird bug obviously). It is not supposed to be edited anyway.

**Edit** : I just edited the field name to `password_request_count` because `password_req_count` already exists in another table. But the bug is still here.

**RECAP HERE**

**Edit 2** : Here is a video because apparently the post is not clear enough. Notice that I can't do the UPDATE query again by pressing the "up" touch, and *please* also notice that start_timestamp gets edited if I **increment** password_req_count.
http://www.nx-lab.com/bug.mp4

**Edit 3** : Apparently this also happens if I edit other fields (such as top_prize)

Comment: Can you provide the schema for `tournaments`?  Also are there any triggers associated with the table?

Comment: How do I provide a schema? And no, I don't even know how to use triggers, so obviously no there is no trigger.

Comment: Running `mysqldump --no-data -p database-name` should dump out all of the schema for the database `database-name`.

Comment: @joncloud I got the schema you asked for, I'm just going to put it on pastebin. Unless you want me to execute what you just said. And thanks for helping! Edit : here it is https://pastebin.com/72XQfVwx

Comment: You should lookup ```TRIGGER ON UPDATE BEFORE``` to update the count column. This would take care of the first query. With an ```IF``` statement, you could check to see if the column is set to 0, and deal with that separately. You say you're updating a timestamp column, but don't show a query that does that. Also, the "bug" isn't clear in your question. Is it that a previous query doesn't appear in the console with an up arrow?

Comment: @SloanThrasher I am updating an int column, not a timestamp one. The timestamp one is the one that gets edited while I make a query to update the int column. This is the bug I'm talking about.

Comment: What is modifying the timestamp? I don't see anything in your question that shows that. IOW, when you update the int column, how is the timestamp column edited? What's the difference between "update" and "edited"?

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. That should reflect your debugging process anyway. But aparently it doesn't because it's not already in your question. Without that your question is off-topic. Edit anything that can be expressed via text into your question as text. (Use code format for code & tables). Using images only for supplemental info. Make your question self-contained (if you have the rep.)

Comment: You say "This query modifies a timestamp field called start_timestamp" but your code clearly doesn't. Your question is unclear and missing much. Please edit your question enough that someone could use it to write the code you need. It's not even clear what your "bug" is or what question you are asking.

Comment: @philipxy I read that some time ago. How am I supposed to give you verifiable examples if I can't even make it myself on localhost? Take a look at this https://pastebin.com/9sk5u9ju because it *perfectly* describes my problem. Remember that I don't even know how to make triggers, so I don't think that triggers are the problem. Also, the field's value stays the same until I execute that one query.

Comment: @philipxy this is what I am talking about... I have **no code** editing that field, and yet it still gets edited. Look at my last reply, and look at the code I am executing. There is no code executing anywhere else, this is done on console. Am I missing something??

Comment: Alright you seem to not understand my problem. My code is perfectly fine ok? The problem is somewhere else, because I already gave you the **whole** code, and see I'll give it again ; `UPDATE tournaments SET password_req_count = password_req_count + 1 WHERE id = 20;`, there is clearly NO other code executed. After doing this, I can simply go to phpmyadmin and notice that "password_req_count" as well as "start_timestamp" have both been edited. Do you need more informations? I can record this on video for you if you want.

Comment: I have recorded it on video. I'll post it soon, please check it out and tell me what else I can do. You will see my whole problem and my whole code there.

Comment: @philipxy So, here is the video : http://www.nx-lab.com/bug.mp4 and now please tell me what else can I do?

Comment: That is not what my comments say. They say to write a clear question using text. PS You are querying a database. It has a definition, DDL code. The definition can involve code that is executed. Put it in your question.

Comment: I do not understand your answer. And I think I'll give up on this, even if everything was purely logic and not due to a bug somewhere in MySQL, when you press the "up" key, the query should appear, and the only query that does not appear is the one that is bugged for me. I give up, forget it. And thanks for the down vote. And even if I'm not able to write "good" questions, note that I'm a quite experienced programmer, so I'm not likely to ask for easy and simple questions, mostly not on Stackoverflows, and mostly **not** before spending **hours** on google/debugging hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a couple of things doing this, one is a trigger on the table. This code will show you if there are any...

```
SHOW TRIGGERS FROM tournaments;
```

The other thing, which is the correct answer in this case, is an auto update on the datetime column. This causes the date and time in the column to be updated automatically when there is an update to the table.

You can read more about it here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html

If you want to remove to auto update then an ALTER table is required to remove it from the column, from [Timestamp without change on update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131725/timestamp-without-change-on-update)...

```
ALTER TABLE leads MODIFY added_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Thank you I was searching for that query. But unfortunatly... `mysql> SHOW TRIGGERS FROM crtourneys;
Empty set (0.00 sec)`

At least there is finally someone that gets that my question is about something that is not even logic. (PS : I write `crtourneys` because that's the database name, `tournaments` is the table name... so it just says `ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'tournaments'` otherwise)

Comment: There might be an auto update on the datetime column as described here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: This post seems to describe how to remove it with an alter table statement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131725/timestamp-without-change-on-update

Comment: I feel like that's the answer I was needing... I'll try that right now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please Answer with what you said in the comments, I'll accept that as the answer. You're saving me, thank you so so much. I would have deleted this post because I got down voted... but I'll keep it just for you. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Glad I was able to help. I have updated the answer and given you question an up vote since it is perfectly valid.