# Why is a field updated that is not part of the UPDATE request?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsp, struts

I am making a UI showing a table using `Struts`, `JSP` where the user can update a record in a table.

The update query `UpdateExchangeRate.xml` is:

```
<query xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="callType.xsd">
  <statement>
     update EXCHANGE_RATES set Code = ?, RATE = ?, DATE_UPDATED = ? where START_DT = ? and END_DATE = ?
  </statement>
   <parms>
      <parm datatype="VARCHAR" type="IN"/>
      <parm datatype="DECIMAL" type="IN"/>      
      <parm datatype="DATE" type="IN"/>
      <parm datatype="DATE" type="IN"/>
      <parm datatype="DATE" type="IN"/>
   </parms>
   <datasource>mysql</datasource>
</query>
```

`exchange_rates.xml`:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="page.xsd">
<columns>
    <group id="exchange_rates">
        <column name="START_DT" displayName="Start Date"/>
        <column name="END_DATE" displayName="End Date"/>
        <column name="Code" displayName="Code"/>
        <column name="RATE" displayName="Rate"  />
        <column name="DATE_UPDATED" displayName="Date Updated"  />
    </group>
</columns>
<javascript>yenToDollarExchangeRate.js</javascript>
<daoConfig>
    <operations>
        <operation type="RETRIEVE">
            <dao name="exchange_rates/GetExchangeRate" id="exchangeRate" groupId="exchange_rates" display="table" />
        </operation>
      <operation type="UPDATE">
            <dao name="exchange_rates/UpdateExchangeRate" id="exchangeRate" >
                <param requestParameter="Code" />
                <param requestParameter="RATE" />
                <param requestParameter="DATE_UPDATED"  />
                <param requestParameter="START_DT" />
                <param requestParameter="END_DATE" />
            </dao>
        </operation>
    </operations>
  </daoConfig>
 </page>
```

When the update query is executed everything works fine except the START_DT is updated to the current date.

I dont know why this is happening as i am not even updating START_DT in the update query.

Here is the log:

```
SystemOut,014 [SampleApp] com.app.common.util.DAOFrameworkUtil [DEBUG] - Interpretation of file /xml/dao/exchange_rates/UpdateExchangeRate.xml as Procedure was unsuccessful. Retrying as Query.
SystemOut,022 [SampleApp] com.app.common.dao.GenDAO [INFO ] - callString = 
    update EXCHANGE_RATES set Code = ?, RATE = ?, DATE_UPDATED = ? where START_DT = ? and END_DATE = ?

SystemOut,023 [SampleApp] com.app.common.dao.GenDAO [DEBUG] - parmValues = 
SystemOut,023 [SampleApp] com.app.common.dao.GenDAO [DEBUG] - p value = C
SystemOut,023 [SampleApp] com.app.common.dao.GenDAO [DEBUG] - p value = 870.000
SystemOut,024 [SampleApp] com.app.common.dao.GenDAO [DEBUG] - p value = 2013-09-17
SystemOut,024 [SampleApp] com.app.common.dao.GenDAO [DEBUG] - p value = 2010-08-01 <<---- This is the value that UI should show instead of current date
SystemOut,024 [SampleApp] com.app.common.dao.GenDAO [DEBUG] - p value = 2010-08-31
SystemOut,024 [SampleApp] com.app.common.dao.GenDAO [INFO ] - parmL .size() = 5, parmValues.length = 5
SystemOut,025 [SampleApp] com.app.common.dao.GenDAO [INFO ] - parm.getType() = IN, parm.getDatatype() = VARCHAR
SystemOut,025 [SampleApp] com.app.common.dao.GenDAO [INFO ] - method name = setString
SystemOut,025 [SampleApp] com.app.common.dao.GenDAO [INFO ] - parm.getType() = IN, parm.getDatatype() = DECIMAL
SystemOut,025 [SampleApp] com.app.common.dao.GenDAO [INFO ] - method name = setBigDecimal
SystemOut,026 [SampleApp] com.app.common.dao.GenDAO [INFO ] - parm.getType() = IN, parm.getDatatype() = DATE
SystemOut,026 [SampleApp] com.app.common.dao.GenDAO [INFO ] - method name = setDate
SystemOut,026 [SampleApp] com.app.common.dao.GenDAO [INFO ] - parm.getType() = IN, parm.getDatatype() = DATE
SystemOut,026 [SampleApp] com.app.common.dao.GenDAO [INFO ] - method name = setDate
SystemOut,027 [SampleApp] com.app.common.dao.GenDAO [INFO ] - parm.getType() = IN, parm.getDatatype() = DATE
SystemOut,027 [SampleApp] com.app.common.dao.GenDAO [INFO ] - method name = setDate
SystemOut,027 [SampleApp] com.app.common.dao.GenDAO [INFO ] - Calling query
SystemOut,114 [SampleApp] com.app.common.dao.GenDAO [INFO ] - Query executed successfully
SystemOut,114 [SampleApp] com.app.common.dao.GenDAO [INFO ] - Calling user defined method to create DTO
SystemOut,114 [SampleApp] com.app.common.dao.GenDAO [INFO ] - Attempting to close resultset, statement and connection
SystemOut,115 [SampleApp] com.app.common.dao.GenDAO [INFO ] - resultset, statement and connection closed successfully
```

Why is the `START_DT` field set to the current date?

Please also read my comments below. Thanks

Comment: How is the table you are updating set up? Maybe the field START_DT is auto updating? See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

Comment: @Pieter I think you are right but can you please explain this because by reading it i can understand that sometimes if i use Timestamp datatype which i have used in my table, one of the column gets updated to current time when update is performed to any one of the column in a row but also it is written there that "To prevent the column from updating when other columns change, explicitly set it to its current value." so my question is why this is happening in my case as you can see i am specifying value for all the column including the one which gets updated automatically. Pl Help

Comment: @Pieter I got it. I am not updating the column which gets updated automatically. But now my question is how can I prevent it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE_RATES
    MODIFY COLUMN START_DT TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;
```

This statement is just an illustration, so be careful using it (e.g. I don't know if your initial column can be null or not).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)
Also i found some other ways here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844863/mysql-updating-entry-without-updating-timestamp