# Touch MYSQL record to update TIMESTAMP field

Tags: mysql, sql

In my Database i have a table with column

```
`LastUpdated` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

i would like to Touch a record in that table so that `LastUpdated` column will be automatically updated but i don't want to change any value in that row.

Is that possible?

Thank you.

Comment: something like this: `update your_table as a set id = a.id where a.id=<desired_record>` its rude but works

Answer (score 16, accepted):

AFAIK, You don't have options to  use `touch` to update mysql table records like you touch file in `unix` systems. You have to issue an update query to `update` the `timestamp` in the `LastUpdated` column .

```
UPDATE mytable SET LastUpdated=NOW() WHERE ...
```