# Yii2 TimestampBehavior not working correctly

Tags: php, yii2

I am using most recent version of Yii framework (2.0.6). I have table Post with PostModel and in my model I need to set correctly `created_at` and `updated_at` properties. As soon as I create new Post, both values are set to current timestamp, but when I update this post, it will also update both attributes in table to current time, even though only `updated_at` should be updated and `created_at` should remain the same.

```
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;

public function behaviors() {
    return [
        [
                'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
        ],
        [
                'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
                'attribute' => 'name',
        ],
    ]; 
}
```

This is the other version, but still not working:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'timestamp' => [
            'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
            'attributes' => [
                \yii\db\ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_at', 'updated_at'],
                \yii\db\ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['updated_at'],
            ],
        ],
        [
            'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
            'attribute' => 'title',
        ],
    ];
}
```

I am also using MariaDB database. If you could help me, what is going on with my code, I will appreciate it very much.

Comment: Do you store time like int or date|datetime ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the second snippet is not correct, because `attributes` array is not designed to be set by user. It's kind of inner logic, you only need to set `createdAtAttribute` and `updatedAtAttribute` properties. Accordingly they are named `created_at` and `updated_at` by default, so if your naming is the same, you can just omit this declaration as you did in first snippet.

It's better to explicitly add this too:

```
use yii\db\Expression;

...

`value` => new Expression('NOW()'),
```

To prevent changing `created_at` column value during update, you can add `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Here is snippet from migration:

```
use yii\db\Schema;

...

'created_at' => Schema::TYPE_TIMESTAMP . ' NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
'updated_at' => Schema::TYPE_TIMESTAMP . ' NOT NULL',
```

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844863/mysql-updating-entry-without-updating-timestamp) for more details.

It's for MySQL, but I guess for MariaDB is the same or very similar.

Comment: This also didn't work, so I added this logic to beforeSave method of this model to solve this problem, even though I am little bit sad that I didn't solve this using build in TimestampBehavior.