# MySQL: Updating entry WITHOUT updating timestamp WHEN using update ... join

Tags: mysql

I have a table like

```
create table test (
    id int,
    a int,
    mtime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
);
```

Under normal circumstances, I need mtime auto update when I modify the record. But sometimes I need keep mtime unchanged.

Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844863/mysql-updating-entry-without-updating-timestamp). From that, I get what I need is this statement:

```
update table test set a = 3, mtime = mtime;
```

It works almost perfectly, except **ONE CASE** : **update ... join ...**. For example,

```
UPDATE test
JOIN
    (select test.id from test
    JOIN middle on middle.test_id = test.id
    JOIN test_2 on middle.test_2_id = test_2.id
    WHERE test_2.id = 3) tmp
ON test.id = tmp.id
SET test.a = 4, test.mtime = test.mtime
```

It changed mtime in table test exactly. So, what should I do for this?

------------- EDIT -----------
It doesn't work, either:

```
update test
join middle on test.id = middle.test_id
join test2 on test2.id = middle.test2.id
set test.a = 3, test.mtime = test.mtime
where test2.id = test2.id + 4;      -- after test, set tset2.id = 4 works,
```

Comment: If you only need it updated sometimes, then don't default the value.  Instead, update it when you want it updated.

Comment: This would be a bug. What is your MySQL-version? If it is a current MySQL version, send in a bugreport. You could work around it e.g. in your first join query by adding `mtime` to your select list of your subquery and setting `mtime = tmp.mtime`.