# How to ignore timestamp column for a particular column

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I have a table user. There is a field **date_last_update** with type **timestamp** , default **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP**, extra **on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP**.
There is another column last_exported_date with type datetime. When user data get exported to excel, last_exported_date get updated to today datetime. So date_last_update column value get updated.

Is there any way I can update ***last_exported_date*** without updating ***date_last_update*** column ?

Comment: Yes, but I think you should remove the `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` part on your table

Comment: @Krishnakumar, If other columns are updated, I think then date_last_update will not be updated too.

Comment: yes... obviously..

Comment: Sorry, I think you did not goet my question. Only date_last_update column value will not be  updated only if last_exported_date colun is updated. For updating of other column, it should updated date_last_update column.

Comment: Yes.. I understood.. I think that specific req is not possible...

Comment: This trick helped to solve my requirement.                https://stackoverflow.com/a/2844893/1926138