# Exclude some fields from updating a field with default value of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL with 4 fields as `id`, `name`, `gender` and `timestamp`.
Default value of timestamp is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` so if name or gender changes, timestamp updates to current date and time.
I want to exclude gender field from updating that timestamp.
Is that possible?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I edited my question but there is not any code really! Just a simple table.

Comment: There is no "simple" way to do this. A "clean" way might be to outsource that column to another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a MySQL Trigger to accomplish this. You did not provide a table name so I'll call your table *PERSON*.

The trigger should look something like the following:

```
delimiter ;;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `TRIGGER_PERSON_AFTER_UPDATE`;;

CREATE TRIGGER `TRIGGER_PERSON_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON PERSON
FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
   IF (NEW.name != OLD.name) THEN
      NEW.time_stamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
   END IF;
 END;;

delimiter ;
```

Comment: I didn't used triggers before. This is a good practice for me. Thanks! I should remove default value of timestamp. Is that correct?

Comment: I would keep the default value so that your time_stamp column gets set on your **INSERT** into the database table.

Comment: I got the idea. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the same value for `timestamp` when updating `gender`. I assume that if you change other fields together with `gender`, then timestamp should update.

```
UPDATE my_table SET gender = ?, `timestamp`=`timestamp`
```

Comment: So there is not any way to define table as I want it?

Comment: No, see alternative by Gabriel. Also a similar question has been asked before, not sure if helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2844893/1839439